# How to send JQuery.Ajax() to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to POST some Ajax data to my PHP application (using XAMPP), but haven't been able to figure out why I can't 'echo' the value on the server side (in the browser).

I have my client side: localhost:8080/test/test.html, which looks like this:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "welcome.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name:"Jay"},
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("success");
        window.location = "welcome.php";
    }
});                                                         
</script>
```

And I also have my PHP script on http://localhost:8080/test/welcome.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["name"]))
        echo $_POST["name"];
    else
        echo "something went wrong";
 ?>
```

It seems that `$_POST["name"]` is undefined, as the `else` is executed. But shouldn't it echo 'Jay'?

I've looked at similar stackoverflow questions/answers and I just can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I've changed $_POST to $_REQUEST, I've changed echo to print_r and even to var_dump. Nothing seems to work. I've added datatype : 'json', put in the content-type, changed the json key to a string, etc, etc.

When I look in the Chrome 'dev tools' after I've executed test.html, I can see in the 'network' tab that there is form data with **name:jay**. So I'm not sure what's wrong....

Any help would be really appreciative.

Thanks :)

Comment: You appear to be confused. You need to do something with `result`, not just redirect (which is a GET request) to the same page.

Comment: Try console.log(result) in your success callback and look at your console you should see the name there. window.location makes your browser change the window location (aka url in the address bar) to the location specified which is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: How **exactly** did you determine that the given data has not been submitted?

Comment: The whole idea about AJAX is that you don't leave the page, but rather refresh a section of the page you're already on. If you do need to leave the page, use a `GET` variable. The reason why your value is is lost is because your AJAX function sends the `POST` variable, then when it's done that, you go to your page, causing a refresh, and now your value is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using AJAX for in your case is unnecessary, since you are leaving the page either way. What you're essentially doing is posting a variable to a page, then when that has happened, you go to that page, but the order of action becomes something like this:

1. `POST` variable
2. Success
3. Leave current page

The `POST` variable will essentially be lost in your current process, because it's like you're causing a refresh by going to the other page.

One of the huge advantages in using AJAX, and what its main purpose is really, is that you can refresh content on your page without causing a reload. Otherwise, why not simply use a `<form>` element instead?

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <!-- form content -->
</form>
```

Or a function that parses a `GET` variable?

```
<script>
function sendNameAsGET(name="Jay") {
    window.location = "welcome.php?name="+name+";
}
</script>
```

However, if it is your intent to refresh the contents of your page without leaving the page in the process, then you're going about it in a wrong way. What you need to think about is have a container that you load your content into.

For instance:

```
<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
```

If this was to be your container, you could have an AJAX function that loads in static content (or simply add it directly). The way to load in content to a container is by using the `.html();` function with a selector of our choice.

Example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "some-static-content.php",
        data : { /* data if necessary */ },
        success: function (html) {
            $("#ajaxDiv").html(html);
        }
    })
});
```

In the above example we are loading the HTML contents of a page named *some-static-content.php* into a container that has the `id` *ajaxDiv*.

Another good reason to use AJAX is that you can now structure your content into different files, making it a lot easier to have a very neat structure. *"Oh, if I need to edit this specific content, I just go to /this/directory/and-this-file.php"*. No need to go into one file, scroll through thousand lines of code to find your section. It becomes a lot like building blocks or Legos that you can dynamically interchange to fit your needs.

And to change the contents of your container with the HTML in your *welcome.php* file, without refreshing the page:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url: "welcome.php",
    data: { name : "Jay" },
    success: function (html) {
        //Success handling
        console.log("success");
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(html);
    }
});
```

Now the *ajaxDiv* container will load in your new content from *welcome.php* and you'll be able to use your `POST` variable. If you `echo` out the `POST` variable in your *welcome.php* then that will be what's now displayed in the *ajaxDiv* container as opposed to the old contents of *some-static-content.php*.

Comment: The reason why I decided to use Ajax is because I'm making use of a javascript API that 'gets' the name of the person currently logged in. It made sense to me, using Ajax, as I was already within the <script> tags, and send this directly to my PHP (where I do additional server side functions, like inserting it into a database etc). I wasn't entirely sure of how to use the html forms when I was inside these tags. In terms of reloading the page, this isn't really an issue for me. What method would you recommend?

Comment: I'll further add that I know I could have a HTML form element with hidden <input>, and use javascript to change the value of those inputs (with say, getElementById). But this seems almost hacky/tacky, as I don't need any user input, and I just need to POST a variable that I get from a javascript API GET request.

Comment: In that case, you can do what you have now exactly, but don't redirect to that page. Rename that page to some sort of action instead. Then once you've done all the server side stuff, then redirect to your welcome.php page which fetches all the data from the database that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Added a Fifth point.

There's a couple of things going on in this. Let's think about the reasoning.

One: why send the data if you are just going to be going to the page? It looks like the post is getting confused as it's sending then going to a page without it's value. It's thinking "Hey that was successful now let me go to the page without the value." In the best way to explain it's like you're resubmitting your form again.

Two: **Why** do you need Ajax for this?

If your welcome page is going to do something specific, like in your above example, why do you need JS? Couldn't you just have your form going to that page? Like

`<form action="welcome.php" method="post">`

Posts are usually form related and not about sending data.

Three: This is gonna get convoluted. Again I would look into Why you're doing it like this because this isn't best.

I would make the result a cookie, then redirect to the page, and set the variable to that cookie.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "welcome.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name:"Jay"},
    success: function (result) {
        console.dir(result); // then we can find out everything about our result
        document.cookie = "cookiename=result.name"
        window.location = "welcome.php";
    }
});
```

Five: Ok let's look at this again on the welcome.php (I just thought of this as I was doing something else)

After we send the value to the php page we could create a session or php cookie.

JS Can stay the same

```
$.ajax({
    url: "welcome.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {name:"Jay"},
    success: function (result) {
        console.dir(result); 
        // then we can find out everything about our result
        window.location = "welcome.php";
    }
});
```

welcome Forgive me my php is a bit rusty

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["name"])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["sessionName"]=$_POST["name"];
}


if (isset($_SESSION["sessionName"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["sessionName"];
else {
    echo "something went wrong";
}

?>
```